# Elegant way around gap between edge of div and contents

Tags: html, css

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spycho/kcWQw/4/), there is a 1px gap between the background of the links and the background of the #content div in most browsers, at most levels of zoom (no idea why zoom seems to affect it). This appears to be because the div containing the links takes up one more pixel at the top and bottom than the links themselves.

I can fix it in a hacky way by giving it a negative margin-bottom, but I would like a more elegant, cross-browser solution. Any ideas?

Comment: I went with the inline-block approach, which I think is semantically best. If you like, you can see solution applied to the original problem [here](http://www.crjbrett.com/) (the menu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most elegant (and "closest to what you had") solution is to use `display: inline-block` on `a`:

http://jsfiddle.net/kcWQw/8/

Comment: This works, is simple, and sounds semantically correct. I think this is better than the line-height approach, because this way, it preserves the increased line-height.

Answer (score 4):

Adding 1px of padding to the links closed the gap.

If you don't like/can't do that for whatever reason, increasing the `line-height` might also fix it.

Comment: That seems to do the trick, but it doesn't seem as though I should have to.

Comment: Welcome to the world of web development. :P You mentioned `line-height:1` works, I'd go with that instead, probably. It's probably more stable and should only really change if you change the font.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a reset CSS fixes the issue : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/kcWQw/5/

I've used Eric [Meyer's reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). You'll need to add additional styling to get things back the way you like it though, but the reset will have taken care of any quirks.

Comment: The only relevant (to the problem) rule in that reset is the `line-height`.

Comment: Yes, setting line-height: 1; on the div that contains the links does the trick. This seems like a pretty good solution, but would it be better practice to go with @thirtydot's inline-block approach?

Comment: @spycho possibly, I only dabble in the dark art of CSS :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use floats to make things stack more neatly - have a look at this fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/Ts7TL/

If you don't walt to use floats, try looking cloesly at the line-heights - that might help.

As also mentioned below - a using a css reset is always good practice.

Comment: It works, but I would rather avoid using float if possible. It seems semantically incorrect. Thanks though.

Comment: I'm not sure where this idea of floats being semantically incorrect comes from? Having said that thi inline-block seems much neater.

Comment: I think in this particular case, floating the elements is semantically incorrect because removing spacing is not the purpose of float. I try to write CSS that clearly has meaning. I would try to only define the float property if I actually wanted to float something. The display approach seems more semantically correct, because changing the box model to one that does not leave a space is precisely what we are attempting to do here. Don't get me wrong, your solution works, and if there wasn't a neater alternative, I would go with something like this. Hence the up-vote.

Comment: Fair enough - wasn't disagreeing, just wondering. There's some pretty fundamental flaws in floats anyway so I agree that they're best avoided where possible - just interested in others opinions! Thanks...